# Request handling methods in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Which method is better to used to handle the request whether to use `requestHandle`  of `AbstractController` or `formBackingObject` of `AbstractFormController` in the spring framework?

Comment: it depends. And there are more options.

Comment: @Vipul: There are a dozen different ways, you'll need to to give us more information than one sentence. And which version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not much information given...

If you are a beginner and not tied to any spcific version of Spring I'd suggest looking at the spring 3.0 MVC implementation.

It is annotation driven so you can define your own methods to use.

See here for docs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-features